# My python code is not writing or reading files correctly, do not know what is wrong?

Tags: python, linux, function

I am still pretty novice at python and using it in Linux but I do not understand what is going wrong here. I have the files imported in the beginning on my system. I am not getting any errors but I know that sometimes option 2 is not actually writing in the file. I also am unable to repeat option 1 for some reason. Help would be very greatly appreciated. The menu section works just fine I believe but there is just some error within MonthlySalary and/or Display_salary.

```
import os
salary=open('Regular_emp.txt','r')
hourly=open('Hourly_emp.txt','r')


def readEmployee(salary,hourly):
    for line in salary:
        line=line.strip()
        number,name,salary=line.split(',')
        print(number, "," , name)
    for line in hourly:
        line=line.strip()
        number,name,wage,hours=line.split(',')
        print(number, "," , name)
    print("")
   
def monthlySalary(salary,hourly):
    paycheck=open('Paychecks.txt','w')
    for line in salary:
        line=line.strip()
        number,name,salary=line.split(',')
        monthly=int(salary)/12
        paycheck.write(str(number)+','+str(name)+','+str(format(monthly,'.2f')+"\n"))
    for line in hourly:
        line=line.strip()
        number,name,wage,hours=line.split(',')
        monthly=int(wage)*int(hours)
        paycheck.write(str(number) + "," + str(name) + ','+str(format(monthly,'.2f'))+"\n")
    paycheck.close()

def display_paycheck():
    open('Paychecks.txt','r')
    checkFile=os.path.getsize("Paychecks.txt")
    while True:
        if checkFile== 0:
            print("")
            print("Please enter option 2 first to create paycheck file")
            print("")
            break
        else:
            for line in paycheck:
                line=line.strip()
                number,name,paycheck=line.split(',')
                print(number, "," , name,",",paycheck)
    print("")

def menu():
    print("Your options include:")
    print("1. Display all employee details from both input files")
    print("2. Calculate Monthly payment of all individuals")
    print("3. Display paycheck details of all employees")
    print("4. Exit the Program")
    print("")
    answer=input("Which option would you like?(Enter 1,2,3 or 4 to exit)")
 
    while True:
        if answer == "1":
            readEmployee(salary,hourly)
        elif answer=="2":
            paychecks=monthlySalary(salary,hourly)    
        elif answer=="3":
            display_paycheck()
        elif answer == "exit" or answer == "4":
            confirmation=input("Are you sure you would like to exit?(enter yes or no)")
            if confirmation == "yes":
                break  
        else:
            print("Error has Occured please try again.")
        print("Your options include:")
        print("1. Display all employee details from both input files")
        print("2. Calculate Monthly payment of all individuals")
        print("3. Display paycheck details of all employees")
        print("4. Exit the Program")
        print("")
        answer=input("Which option would you like?(Enter 1,2,3 or 4 to exit)")
menu()
```

The files I am referencing are:
Regular_emp.txt

1001, 'name 1', 48000.00

1002, 'name 2', 55000.00

1003, 'name 3', 60000.00

and
Hourly_emp.txt

2001, 'name 4', 15.00, 160

2002, 'name 5', 20.00, 125

2003, 'name 6', 35.00, 123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In option 2 you need to iterate over `fileobject.read()`. As `salary` and `hourly` themselves if just file objects.

```
def monthlySalary(salary, hourly):
    paycheck = open('Paychecks.txt', 'w')
    # Here
    for line in salary.read():
        line = line.strip()
        number, name, salary = line.split(',')
        monthly = int(salary)/12
        paycheck.write(str(number)+','+str(name)+',' +
                       str(format(monthly, '.2f')+"\n"))
    # And here
    for line in hourly.read():
        line = line.strip()
        number, name, wage, hours = line.split(',')
        monthly = int(wage)*int(hours)
        paycheck.write(str(number) + "," + str(name) +
                       ','+str(format(monthly, '.2f'))+"\n")
    paycheck.close()
```

I recommend handing files in this method

```
# Writing
with open("file.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("test")

# Reading
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    contents = f.read()
```

So the file is automatically closed at the end of the `with` indentation. Keeping the file opened for a short amount of time.

You are probably having the same issue with option 1.

Comment: I have updated my code to exactly what you have but the Paychecks.txt is still empty at the end. Also when I add the .read() to option1 I get the error of expected 3 arguments, got 1.

Comment: Could you add an example of the two txt files to your question please? just so we can reproduce an example

Comment: I have added what the files contain to the question. I have also figured out option 1 as it does not repeat, so my only issue is 2 and 3. Also thank you for the help, it is greatly appreciated

Comment: I Actually just got it to work!! Thank you so much for the help. I had to reopen the files repeatedly under each function to make it work but it works!

Comment: No worries Sierra :)